# CSS DropDown Menu items overlapping eachother

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dropdown menu based on suckerfish.  The top level appears correctly, however the first submenu level puts all the menu items stacked over top of eachother right under the top level.  Everything is correct except the items are overlapping.  My html and css are below.

```
 <ul id="nav">
   <li style="border-left: none;">
        <link here>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <link here>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <link here>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <link here>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <link here>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <link here>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <link here>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <link here>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <link here>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <link here>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <link here>
    </li>
    <li>
        <link here>
    </li>
    <li>
        <link here>
    </li>
    <li>
        <link here>
    </li>
</ul>


#nav, #nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    margin: -1em 0 0 10em;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    line-height: 1;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

My CSS is pulled pretty much straight from suckerfish.  there are a few small changes like the widths and background color, but the issue was there even when it was a direct copy.  Currently I am only trying to get this to in firefox, as I am getting the same issue in every browser I try.

Just an fyi, I am using umbraco as the CMS for this site, and it is generating the html for the menu.  There are actual links I just cant post them as I am new here, they contain just the hfer attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the suckerfish technique doesn't support dual nested lists. Which means, a UL can be nested as deep as you want (if the CSS supports it of course) but what it can't do is style 2 UL's on the same level.

Please check my revised HTML (without dual nested UL's).

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li style="border-left: none;">
        <a href="#">Test link</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Test link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Test link 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test link</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Test link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Test link 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also [check it online](http://www.damienvanholten.com/labs/dropdown/).

On a side note, your CSS for the items and second level UL's seems to need some work (they float wrong now - depending on how you want it to look of course).

Comment: Yep, that was it, didn't see the unnecessary ULs  Thanks